# Is ther any tool in ubuntu to convert pdf to doc

Tags: pdf, rails, ruby-on-rails, doc

I am looking for a tool or middle-ware which converts PDF to DOC. which should convert exact PDF content (with all image and style.)

I have tried **abiword**. No use. not converting properly.

If we can able to save pdf as word in **libreOffice**, How to do that in command line.

**Note:-**
*I want it to use in my rails application. i am trying to provide a feature in my application to get convert pdf to word. So it should be done from my server. So online converters are not going to use here.*

Answer (score 1):

If to you had trouble with AbiWord and LibreOffice I don't think you will find a way to have a proper conversion.

You can still try to use an online converter such as [PdfEscape](http://www.pdfescape.com/) for example.
Make sure to check their [Privacy Policy](http://www.redsoftware.com/privacy/) before sending personal documents.

Comment: i want this in server. please see the update and help me out

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there are no free open source solutions for this. If you search for "PDF to RTF API" there are several products that will do the conversion for a license fee, either offline (using a set of programming libraries) or online (through a web service that you can build into your application). Choose whatever suits you best.